# How to get all latlng of Route between two points in OSM

Tags: java, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm working on app using open street map. I have draw route between two points. I want to get list of all latitudes and longitudes on the route polyline. If anyone knows please answer me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you already take a look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing?

Comment: yeh, i tried to get all latitudes and longitudes of may route, and i get it.'Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road1)' 'roadOverlay.getPoints();'

Comment: Next time please mention that your question is about osmdroid. This isn't visible at all from your question. I've added the osmdroid tag for you.

Comment: I perfectly understood that this question is about OSM, that's why I pointed you to the routing section in the OSM Wiki. However osmdroid is just *one of many* OSM frameworks. Your question seems to be specific about osmdroid, not about OSM in general.

Comment: Ok next time I will try to compose my question more precisely. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the answer
just play with your polyline **

Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road1);
roadOverlay.getPoints();